# finding the distance from a point to a line in vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

How shall I prove that the distance from the point with position vector $"c"$ to the line $r=a+\lambda b$ is given by ${\mid(c-a)ʌb\mid}\ /\ \mid b\mid$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

See the picture bellow:

[image]

Recall that:
$$|(c-a) \times b|= |(c-a)||b| \sin \theta$$
But from the picture we can derive that:
$$d=|(c-a)| \sin \theta$$
Hence
$$|(c-a) \times b|= |b| d \Rightarrow$$
$$d=\frac{|(c-a) \times b|}{|b|}$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof is comming accessible [here>>>](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)
Particularly see from eq 6 down there.